# OneWay/TwoWay binding in XAML using Lambda expression and MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I can not bind the `Combobox.SelectedItem`in `XAML` in my `ViewModel` using the `MVVM` pattern with `lambda`expressions.

In my `MainWindow.xaml` i have:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" IsEnabled="{Binding ProductsIsEnabled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" />
```

In my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I have the `DataContext` correctly set (all other pieces of my code in `xaml` work just fine).

In my `MainWindowViewModel.cs` I have:

```
...
public string TitleText => Title.Text;
...
public ObservableCollection<object> Products => MyConverter.GetCollection(ProductList);
public bool ProductsIsEnabled => MyProduct.IsEnabled;
public object SelectedProduct => ProductList.SelectedItem; // --> this does not work
...
```

The error i receive when running is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'SelectedProduct' of type 'MyNamespace.MainWindowViewModel'.
```

All my objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
Does anybody know what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public object SelectedProduct => ProductList.SelectedItem;` is a short form for

```
public object SelectedProduct
{
  get
  {
    return ProductList.SelectedItem;
  }
}
```

That means a property with a lambda Expression is a property without a setter; it is a read-only property. `SelectedItem` of the combo box can be changed by the user, that means the user can change the value of the `SelectedProduct` property.

To fix it, you'll have either to at a setter to the property or you'll have to change the binding two one way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" IsEnabled="{Binding ProductsIsEnabled}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

One-Way-Binding means that the property stays unchanged if the user changes it. Only if you change the property, the UI element will change.

Addendum: After I read your comment: Your property `ProductList.SelectedItem` can have a getter and a setter, but from that it does not mean that your property `SelectedProduct` will have a setter and a getter. Change it to

```
public object SelectedProduct
    {
      get
      {
        return ProductList.SelectedItem;
      }
      set
      {
        ProductList.SelectedItem = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedProduct)));
      }
    }
```

and it should work.

Comment: thanks, i think though that i need a TwoWay binding, if i need both that the combobox updates its list of items from my viewmodel, as well as that the combo can select an item and pass it to me, right? I tried setting in `Mode=TwoWay` to see, but didn't compile...

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly like this, and there's no need (for a combobox) to set `Mode=TwoWayBinding` in xaml, seems to be its default mode; do you know a way two summarise your solution with the `set`ters and `get`ters with lambdas? (just curious about)